Azure Web Availability test is not getting stopped
We are using below CLI task to stop and start the availability test alert rules and and the availability tests.
But its noticed that, sometimes, some alert rules/apptest are still running/stopped on portal, even after the successful run of the below tasks.
When we execute this cli commands manually from the server using the same ServicePrincipal used inn azuredevops service connection) , its getting stopped.
      - task: AzureCLI@2
        displayName: "Stopping Availability Test and Alert ${{ availabilityTestprd.name }} in Production"
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: "xxxxxxxxxx"
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
             echo "availabilityTestprd is ${{ availabilityTestprd.name }}"
             echo "RG is  ${{ availabilityTestprd.rg }}" 
             az config set extension.use_dynamic_install=yes_without_prompt
             az monitor app-insights web-test update --name ${{ availabilityTestprd.name }} --resource-group ${{ availabilityTestprd.rg }} --enabled false
             az monitor metrics alert update --enabled false --name ${{ availabilityTestprd.name }} --resource-group ${{ availabilityTestprd.rg }}


Is it showing any error? @Vowneee

No errors.. it runs successfully, but not getting stopped in the portal.

Have you tried refreshing the portal results? @Vowneee

I tried in developer Azure CLI, and it was working fine with the relevant commands and should work fine with the DevOPs yaml as well. @Vowneee

Can you try adding the echo print conditions after each command execution and verify? @Vowneee


Alert rules/apptest are still running/stopped on portal, even after the successful run of the below tasks.

The above was temporary one which might be occurred due to some cache issue or CLI command execution issue with DevOps yaml script pipelines.
You can try including a test condition inside the yaml script as detailed in the endtest blog here. These test conditions execute after the command execution and also provide exact output details if any conflict has blocked the command operations.
yaml:
for i in {1..3}; 
do
 status=$(az monitor metrics alert show --name firstalerts --resource-group caronew --query "disabled" -o tsv)
 if [ $status == "true" ]
 then
    result=$status && echo "Successfully disabled"
 elif [ $status == "false"]
    echo "Failed" && break
 else
    exit 0
 fi
done

I have tried to create a web test and update it by using Azure CLI commands and was able to execute it successfully as shown below.
az monitor app-insights web-test create
az monitor app-insights web-test update --name my-webtest-my-component --resource-group caronew --location canadacentral --enabled false


Alert rules also get disabled with the same command as you used in Azure CLI.
az monitor metrics alert update --enabled false --name firstalerts --resource-group caronew

Note: Also try authenticating to Azure App insights directly rather than service principal authentication. If the service principal doesn't have necessary permissions then it results these kind of conflicts.
